# Codeceptjs for API testing - Node.js

Tags: node.js, api, codeceptjs

As mentioned in the title, I wish to use Codeceptjs to test an API.
My issue is that, my system is able to receive the JSON that I'm sending as my request, however I don't think it knows what to run. My hunch is that it has something to do with the URL.

Here is my codecept.json

```
{
  "tests": "./*_test.js",
  "timeout": 10000,
  "output": "./output",
  "helpers": {
    "REST": {
      "endpoint": "http://localhost:3001/",
      "defaultHeaders": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    }
  },
  "include": {
    "I": "./steps_file.js"
  },
  "bootstrap": false,
  "mocha": {},
  "name": "testFiles2"
}
```

And here is a sample with the file name 'samp_test.js'

```
var Factory = require('rosie').Factory;
var faker = require('faker');

Feature('BackgsroundData');

Scenario('Test-BackgroundData', (I) => {
  var args = {
    "LAST_SYNC_DATE": "2010-01-01 10:00:00",
    "CLIENT_ID"     : "0000",
    "BRN_CODE"      : "1",
    "TER_CODE"      : "1",
    "HASH"          : "sampleHash"
  };

  var reqHead = {
    'Accept'    : 'application/json',
    'User-Agent': 'Unirest Node.js',
    'id'        : '1'
  };

  I.haveRequestHeaders(reqHead);
    I.sendPatchRequest('/sync/backgroundData', JSON.stringify(args));   
});
```

Any clue? I'm new to codeceptjs so please excuse me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would like to add that I normally use postman, where I send the same requests and have the process be successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. The issue was the endpoint ending with a slash('\') and the url starting with a slash('\').

Now it's working perfectly.